# How does MATLAB compile a m file?

Tags: matlab-compiler, matlab

I am writing a MATLAB m file which looks like this:

```
for k = 1:100
func_a();
func_b();
func_c();
end
```

where func_a, func_b, and func_c are three different m files each has about 500 lines.
Now, I want to know how MATLAB compiles this code. Does is compile each of the functions 100 times (which would be very tedious) or MATLAB just compile each function once.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

They enabled JIT (Just In Time Compilation), so every loop interprets once, runs several times. [discussed here](http://www.matlabtips.com/matlab-is-no-longer-slow-at-for-loops/)

To check the difference, you can run this command:

```
feature accel off
```

This command would disables the JIT, then all commands would be interpreted even in the loops. You will see the difference ...